# Are Wii U games on external drive transferrable?

Tags: wii-u, hard-drive

If I downloaded some game from eShop onto my external drive, could I take the drive to a friend or family's Wii U and play the downloaded game off the external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid that the game on an external drive are linked to the Wii U itself, and won't show up on any Wii U except for the console it was purchased on.